# Using SQL Developer with BIPublisher Oracle Cloud HCM

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

it's been 2 months I'm working for a new client on BI Reporting on Oracle BI Publisher within an OracleCloud CRM and HCM. to make query to OracleCloud database I have to use notepad++ and then copy/past my query in the Query textArea on BIPublisher  (which is a simple text area without any syntaxe check or color), I was wondering if there are some experts who might know a way to connect SQL Developer to OracleCloud database so I can run my queries directly without copy/past on the browser.
thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct access to the underlying Oracle Database from your SaaS subscription.

We (the SQL Developer team) are working with a few of the SaaS business owners to make SQL Developer Web available for their subscribers. This would allow you to run queries directly against your database w/o having to do the copy/paste jump you're doing today in BI Publisher.

I cannot provide guidance on when this will happen or even if your particular services will make it available.

The TL;DR answer to your question is 'No, but we are working on it'

Comment: thank you so much for your quick and precise answer, at least now I know there is no way to so, I think I'll try to recreate the schema database in localhost and work SQLDev before copy/past it into the BIPublisher, at least there will be syntaxe check. thank you again

Comment: That sounds like a mess. Good job Oracle!

Comment: @EdHayes3 You're buying the application/service, not a database. When the app is running in your data center, it's your database to do with as you please. Obviously it's 'your' data and you want access to it. That's what we're working to make better.

Comment: The irony here, @thatjeffsmith, is that SQL Developer has not found a way to connect the HCM database, when others have clearly demonstrated that this is possible. Take a look at https://github.com/placetaken/OCQv1/wiki